# SQL Server Date Time custom Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server, and I have an procedure like this:

```
 create proc Output1
 (
    @Date_From datetime,
    @Date_To datetime
```

Then I will execute this procedure like this:

```
exec Output1 '03-01-2013 06:00:00AM', '03-31-2013 06:00:00AM'
```

So how can I specified the time of `6:00:00AM` when I executed the procedure but I will only input the date of '03-01-2013', '03-01-2013' but the output still '03-01-2013 06:00:00AM', '03-31-2013 06:00:00AM'?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your stored procedure to set the time part:

```
declare @x datetime = '03-01-2013';
select @x = DateAdd(hh, 6, DateDiff(dd, 0, @x))
print @x
```

More: [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) and [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: ...why bother with `DateDiff`? ...this is fine `select @x = DateAdd(hh, 6, @x)`